# Display Android Toast message in FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-context, fragmentstatepageradapter

I'm trying to display a toast message in a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, which I'm failed.

I need to get context to insert in my code

```
Toast.makeText(, "The message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But I can't use `getContext()`, `getActivity()` cause I don't have any `onCreateView` methods and I don't know any other way to get the context.

Here's my `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` code:

```
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mobaleghan.tablighcalendar.view.fragment.PrayerListViewContainerFragment;
import com.mobaleghan.tablighcalendar.view.fragment.TablighDataTabFragment;

public class TabbedKnowledgeAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private int mNumOfTabs;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    public TabbedKnowledgeAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs, TabLayout tabLayout) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
        this.tabLayout = tabLayout;

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        //Some codes

        Toast.makeText(, "the message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //I need context

        //Some other codes

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

So how can I get context in a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`?

Comment: Try `tabLayout.getContext()` and give a feedback!

Comment: @Xenolion That did the trick!

Comment: Pass Context in FragmentStatePagerAdapter  constructor.

Comment: Added an answer@AlexJolig

Comment: I don't like the idea that a PagerAdapter - the supplier of data for views - depends itself on another view - an object which renders data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
tabLayout.getContext();
```

Comment: This is the solution!

Answer (score -1):

Pass context in your constructor

```
Context context;
public TabbedKnowledgeAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context ctx, int NumOfTabs, TabLayout tabLayout) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    this.tabLayout = tabLayout;
    this.context = ctx;

}
```

And pass this context in your Toast.

Comment: While this would work, it also adds unnecessary complexity. All views including TabLayout already hold an instance of Context (either Activity or its derivate) accesssible by `getContext()`.

Answer (score -1):

Use the application's context

For example

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    //Some codes

    Toast.makeText(((SampleApplication)getApplication()).getApplicationContext(), "the message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //I need context

    //Some other codes

}
```

Comment: PagerAdapters don't have a `getApplication` method.